# Design pattern for executing and reverting the tasks in same order

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, clean-code, readability

I have a Task in my project , to complete that i have call(REST) multiple external systems. If my call fails at some level , i have to rollback all my previous calls(making call with undo action) .

Looking for effective way of implementing it in JAVA. Can Someone point me to any design pattern if exists?

```
    public void myTask(){


        call subtask1() ; //external sys

        try{
            call subtask2();
        }
        catch(Exception){
            call undo_subtask1();
        }

        try{
            call subtask3();
        }
        catch(Exception){
            call undo_subtask1();
            call undo_subtask2();  //calling in any order is fine.
        }

        .....
    }
```

The above code is similar to database rollback. Tomorrow there can be subtask 4, 5,6 . I don't want to add try/catch again. Is there recommended way to achieve this?

When i googled i got [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). But i don't understand how that will help my case.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be problematic if you try to undo an action that failed or never got executed?

Comment: I don't see any problem other than wasting a network call.

Comment: Well, represent your (sub)tasks as objects using the Command pattern - encode both the execute() and undo() operations in each object (your code already has paired methods). Then pass in a *list of commands* to myTask (or make a proper object and store the list as a field, pass to the constructor). Execute one by one; if a command succeeds, go on to the next one, if it fails, go back and call undo() until you reach the first one (reverse the loop, or use a stack, or something), and then exit the method. Then, when you need to add more subtasks, just add new command objects to the list.

Comment: ^ This is under the assumption that you don't want to change the myTask method when new tasks need to be implemented, since  you've said "Tomorrow there can be subtask 4, 5,6 . I don't want to add try/catch again."

Answer (score 3):

If it is not a problem to run the undo action also for the steps that either failed or weren't executed at all, you can just use the fact that an exception will cause the execution of the try block to be stopped with a jump to the catch block.

```
public void myTask()
{
  try
  {
    call subtask1();
    call subtask2();
    call subtask3();
    ...
  }
  catch(Exception){
    ...
    call undo_subtask3();
    call undo_subtask2();
    call undo_subtask1();
    throw; // re-throw the exception
  }
}
```

Adding a new subtask is just adding the corresponding `call subtaskX()`/`call undo_subtaskX()` to the try and catch blocks.

If you want to avoid calling undo actions for subtasks that didn't complete successfully, you could either use nested try blocks, or a set of booleans to indicate which subtasks completed successfully and need to be rolled back in case of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap each pair `undo_subtask1`, `undo_subtask2` etc, in an object

```
interface Subtask {
    void undo();
}
```

We can then put each task into a container, and the cleanup calls all the `undo`s

```
public void myTask() {
  try (List<Subtask> done = new ArrayList<Subtask>())
  {
    subtask1();
    done.add(new Subtask {
      public void undo() { undo_subtask1(); }
    })

    subtask2();
    done.add(new Subtask {
      public void undo() { undo_subtask2(); }
    })

    subtask3();
    done.add(new Subtask {
      public void undo() { undo_subtask3(); }
    })

    ...
  }
  catch(Exception){
    for (Subtask subtask : done)
    {
      subtask.undo();
    }

    throw;
  }
}
```